# DynamoDB storage volume of attribute keys. Do shorter attribute keys and attribute types use less storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was just wondering whether it is useful to have shorter attribute keys in dynamodb. I know this has drawbacks since they are not human readable but thinking of millions of rows this means significant storage volume, at least in my mind.

So, does a  shorter attribute key use less storage?

P.S. side question: how about the types. Can I always use strings or are there advantages of using e.g. numbers or booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, shorter attribute keys use less storage. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html):

> An item size is the sum of lengths of its attribute names and values
>   (binary and UTF-8 lengths).

In terms of [types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes), it is about how you want to model your data and what operations you want to perform on them. If you want to [increment an attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement), you would want to use a `Number` data type. If you want to store a blob of compressed image data you might use the `Binary` data type. If you want a `deleted` attribute on a row you would use the `Boolean` data type. It also depends on if you have indexing requirements for any of these attributes.